# How To Set Area Name in RedirectToAction() Asp.net Mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I Want Set Area Name in Method

```js
 RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
```

Comment: `return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { area = "..." });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do the following:

```
 RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { area = "Area" });
```